# What is the rationale behind Most-Recent-Order for tab switching?

Tags: user-interface, tabs

I can't understand the reasoning behind Most-Recent-Order (how Windows sorts windows when switching via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) when used for tab/window/document/task switching. The way Firefox does tab switching (tabs stay in a consistent order, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for moving to the next/previous tab) seems much more natural than switching in chronological order.

When there are more than ~5 tabs or windows, I quickly forget the chronological order in which they were opened. So the sequence of switching between them becomes difficult to predict. Even if I remember which tab was active before the current one, and which one was active prior to *that*, it just takes a lot of key strokes to switch to these. More than if I could simply use direct order as in Firefox or Chrome.

1. Is there any rational reason to use MRO in an application apart from backward compatibility (for users accustomed to the old hotkeys and usage patterns)?
2. Why is it still used in Windows for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switching between applications?

Comment: This only marginally belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I suspect this might find a more natural home on either Superuser or, more likely, meta.stackoverflow. This is entirely subjective though, it's just I'm not convinced that it's about programming, particularly, more about UI preference.

Comment: This does just barely fit into Stack Overflow perhaps a better place would be:- http://uxexchange.com/ which deals more specifically with user experience issues

Comment: @ricebowl: it certainly doesn't belong on meta, it might belong on Superuser depending on the motive behind the question.

Comment: Why wouldn't this belong here? It's a design question.

Comment: Thanks for link to uxexchange.com, I didn't know about this service so I asked my question here. Sorry for offtopic. Is it better to delete it now? (I don't like this idea myself cause it will delete answers)

Comment: This is no more appropriate on superuser than it is on SO (SuperUser is not your trash bin http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/serverfault-com-is-not-your-trash-bin).  If the question is about how he should **design some software he's writing**, then the question needs to be worded as such.  Right now, it is just taking a poll of what people's preferences are.

Comment: Tried to clean this up a bit - was worded argumentatively and (as Kip noted) appeared to poll for agreement with the author's personal preferences rather than asking for help understanding a particular UI design pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's used because often you're switching between two applications so it's a simple Alt+Tab to switch back and forth.  If it didn't use a most recently used order it could be mulitple keypresses to switch back and forth between the two apps I'm interested in at the moment.

Similarly, in an IDE, I could be switching back and forth between two files and don't want to hit Ctrl+Tab lots of times to keep making the same switch.

Comment: Even when you're dealing with 3 applications, it's still easier to Alt+[TAB,TAB] when you have a lot of applications running.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate it in Windows Alt-Tab switching, but hate it for situations where tabs are visually present at the top of the screen. When I can see the tabs, I want to switch between them in the order I can see them, since I can probably at a glance (and without any conscious effort) count the number of times I need to press tab; and generally I'm working with few enough tabs (I'm an avid hater of clutter) that this works for me.

In Windows, when the alt-tab dialog (if dialog is the appropriate term) doesn't persist, I want to use MRO for switching.

Answer (score 1):

People usually work well with a few items at a time, and the attention span allows us to better concentrate onto a couple of recent pieces of information rather than onto lengthy lists. Think of it in terms of *caching* this recent information: if you've used something in the last couple of seconds, and switched away from it for a moment, it's likely that it will be the first thing that you'll want to use again when you switch.